# Flash AS3 Define Sound End Time

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to play a sound in Flash, but just an interval of the complete sound.
For example, starts at 10 seconds and ends at 15 seconds of the entire sound.

I know how I can set the start point, but I dont how to set the end point.
This is the code that I´m using:

```
var s:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("mp3/mysound.mp3"));  
var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
channel = s.play(start_point);
```

Could you help me guys?

Best, Flavio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no method or property built into Sound that you can make use of, so you'll have to set a timer as well.

```
var s:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("mp3/mysound.mp3"));  
var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var timer:Timer = new Timer(5000, 1);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, stopSound);
timer.start();
channel = s.play(start_point);

function stopSound(e:TimerEvent):void {
  channel.stop();
}
```

It might be just as easy to edit your sound file to get the segment of sound you want too.